# WebView renders layout too small on the first page load

Tags: android, webview

When I open a webview from within the app and load this [page](http://app.anne-eli.at/index.php?id=151) for the first time, it is rendered in the wrong way: the content is rendered in a really thin column. See here:

[image]

As soon as I reload the webview or leave and open the fragment again, everything is fine:

[image]

Killing the app (cleanup memory) makes the bug reproducible. The bug is reproducible on a selection of Android devices.
Any ideas?

------ EDIT -------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_web_view_wv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the WebView init code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_web_view_wv);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    private boolean mShowingProgressbar = false;

    @Override
    public void onReachedMaxAppCacheSize(long spaceNeeded, long totalUsedQuota,
                                         android.webkit.WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
        quotaUpdater.updateQuota(spaceNeeded * 2);
    }

    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
        Log.d("Javascript", message + " ---- From line " + lineNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            progressBarPopup.dismiss();
            mShowingProgressbar = false;
        } else if (!mShowingProgressbar) {
            progressBarPopup.show();
            mShowingProgressbar = true;
        }
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
});

mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);

// Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

String appCachePath = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("anne-eli");
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
// mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(),
// "Android");

// Workaround for the issue:
// https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please share the layout xml or the code where you are initializing the webview

Comment: thats a very good point- havent thought about the possibility that the webview could be layouted in the wrong way. I don't see any reason though (check my edit)...

Comment: ok- its not the android layout- i changed the background colors of the views and its apparently the html rendering which gets messed up.

Comment: Check after commenting 'mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);'

Comment: Have you added a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize WebView settings the following way:

```
WebView webview= (Webview) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_web_view_wv);//initialize webview
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
```

and then load the url.Further you can try zooming in by:

```
webview.setInitialScale(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This look strange but it works in my case,

```
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_web_view_wv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: what? Why should that help? Have you had this problem and you could fix it with setting width and height to wrap_content?

Comment: problem might not with webview settings. It might be in the way the webpage is designed. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of codes:

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

to your `setWebViewClient(...)` to check loading errors.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue, I had to move my content offscreen by adding an arbitrarily large margin-top to the div that contains my content, then moving it back by executing a piece of Javascript when the content is loaded. I realize this is not a solution when you don't have control over the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code :**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>`
```

same problem was in my code, after change above, its working fine.